I have some secrets in my AKS and I need to restrict few secrets from others
I have 10 secrets in dev namespace and I need to restrict only 2 secrets access from others I have enabled Azure RBAC for both authorization and authentication, How to achieve this?
Since I am using Azure RBAC Kubernetes RBAC not application

You cannot really do that. Anyone that deploys Pods in that namespace can get access to all Secrets in that namespace. Namespaces are your security boundaries.

I have few network policy, service account and secrets for admin purpose those dev team  don't want to delete or modify

Putting them in another namespace is the only way to properly do this. Namespaces are the security boundaries in the cluster.
